Is it possible to test for mean difference between groups using GLM in R?
Suppose I have a data set with the number of positives n from total tested N and I wish to test whether there's a significant difference in mean positives between males and females. If I run a GLM model as follows;
> df <- data.table(
+   n = rbinom(100, 5, .6),
+   N = rbinom(100, 10, .9),
+   gender = sample(rep(c('male', 'female')),100, replace = T)
+ )
> mod <- glm(cbind(n, N-n) ~ gender, data = df, family = 'binomial')
> summary(mod)

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(n, N - n) ~ gender, family = "binomial", 
    data = df)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -0.6656     0.1015  -6.558 5.45e-11 ***
gendermale   -0.0534     0.1415  -0.377    0.706    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 64.215  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 64.073  on 98  degrees of freedom
AIC: 317.84

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4


Since the change in log odds between the reference class females and males -0.0534 is not statistically different from zero, does this mean that there's no significant statistical difference in the mean of the two groups. Some reference materials will be highly appreciated

Absolutely, and no need for a GLM; your example is comparing 2 means, and you can use the good old OLS. You may be interested in the following references; a very good blog titled "Common statistical tests are linear models" and R code here, same reference but with Python code here, and a discussion about this topic here

Thanks for this. In addition and in the spirit of testing for mean difference between groups which are clustered, suppose I use the linear mixed effect model, with the random effect as my clusters, will this be also a test of difference?
